# convert bytes to uint8[8] using mstore()

Tags: memory, opcode, assembly

I know how to convert `bytes` to `uint8[8]` using `mload` but `mstore` seemed like it could be more gas efficient.

Is something like this possible?

```
function bytesToUintArray(bytes input) returns (uint8[8])) { 
    uint8[8] result;
    assembly {
        mstore(result, add(input, 32))
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to copy the first 8 bytes from input to the `uint8[8]` array?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but arrays in memory are not tightly packed so you need multiple mstore

From https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.20/assembly.html#conventions-in-solidity

> Elements in memory arrays in Solidity always occupy multiples of 32 bytes (yes, this is even true for byte[], but not for bytes and string).

```
function foo(bytes input) internal pure returns (uint8[8]) {
    uint8[8] memory result;
    assembly {
        let w := mload(add(input, 0x20))
        for { let i:= 0 } lt(i, 8) { i := add(i, 1) } {
            mstore(add(result, mul(i, 0x20)), byte(i, w))
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And the gas consumption is just slightly better than the obvious solution

```
function foo2(bytes input) internal pure returns (uint8[8]) {
    uint8[8] memory result;
    for (uint i=0; i<8 && i<input.length; ++i) {
        result[i] = uint8(input[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a whole library about the topic:

https://github.com/pouladzade/Seriality

Answer (score 0):

You expected this trick to work:

```
function bytesToUintArray2(bytes memory input) public view returns (uint8[8] memory result) { 
    assembly {
        result := add(input, 32)
    }
}
```

But this **would not work** due to `bytes` is stored packed with length prefix like this:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008
1122334455667788000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

But `uint8[8]` is stored non-packed and without length prefix like this:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000033
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000055
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000066
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000077
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000088
```